# Calling a java class through a webpage

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I'm learning about web development. And I'm using jquery $.get method to fetch data from a server through http GET. here is a snippet of my code

js:

```
  $.get("servlet.jsp", function(data){
     alert("first name is: "+ data);
```

jsp:

```
   <%
    Dao users = new Dao();
    out.println(users.fetchLastName("Jack"));
    %>
```

where Dao is a java class that fetch last name of first name Jack from a database.

That produced an internal server error. So does this mean that the method fetchLastName has somehow failed to establish connection to the database even though that it works when I run it normally, or is it that I haven't done the correct mapping of the output?

Comment: Does the error occur when you open the url in your browser?

Comment: no, url opens with no errors, but when I click the button that fires the request. I can see in the network tab of chrome's developer tool the request was made but error in status.

Comment: servlet.jsp is a relative url. Is it possible that the path of your page is different from the path of the servlet.jsp?

Comment: they are in the same directory.

Comment: Using tomcat webserver, and according to their documentation Java classes should be placed in WEB-INF/classes. so thats where I placed my java class

Comment: could you post the log of the server which will be diplayed on console?

Comment: **Do not write scriptlets in JSP**, because scriptlets shouldn't be used in JSPs for more than a decade. Learn the JSP [EL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), the [JSTL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info), and use servlet for the Java code.  
See [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1031945). See [Servlet Ajax answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20758729/1031945). Most useful [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4112686/1031945)